Remove all files in MyDocument except only one file
I'm writing an automation script, in PowerShell, and want it to delete all files (not folders) inside MyDocuments, excluding one file named, for example, office.xlxs.
I'm trying this command:
Get-ChildItem -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) -file | Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "office.xlxs"} | Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path $_.FullName

It didn't work as my intention. When i tested it, it, this command removed all files inside MyDocument. As my research, i can olny filter file by file extension (*.xlxs). But I only wanna keep 1 file with the exact name. Hope anyone can make it more clear and help me out. Thanks in advance!

https://superuser.com/questions/529771/delete-all-folders-and-files-except-for-specified-files

Welcome to SO.
Please format your code properly using a [code block].  What do you mean with "It didn't work as my intention."? What happend or what did not happen?

I just edited it. Sorry when I didn't get in your culture~!

Unbind the Path parameter from the Remove-Item cmdlet since that argument input will come from the pipeline.
The correct command is:
Get-ChildItem -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) -file |
Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "office.xlxs"} |
Remove-Item -Force -Recurse


Why the -Recurse flag, in Remove-Item cmdlet, if you are deleting files only (and not folders)?

Yes, that point can be raised too. I noticed that but I overlooked it since it does no cause more issues whether it is there or not.

-ne isn't case sensitive

Thanks man, i just cannot understand. I use exactly the same command with you and it rm all files in MyDoc.
Example I tried to change the last par from Remove... to Select Name, it shows exactly what I wanted ( It displayed all files name Excluded office.xlxs. But Remove command didn't follow this result somehow. It's pretty weird.

Is your file a Microsoft Excel file ? I think that the extension of your file is not correct. You wrote .xlxs instead of .xls.

You can only use "$_" inside a scriptblock, and usually only with parameters you can pipe to.  You can also use -exclude with get-childitem instead of where-object (with some adjustments).
Get-ChildItem -Path ([Environment]::GetFolderPath("MyDocuments")) -file | 
  Where-Object {$_.Name -ne "office.xlxs"} | 
  Remove-Item -Force -Recurse -Path { $_.FullName } -whatif

What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Users\admin\Documents\aa.pdf".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Users\admin\Documents\ab.csv".
What if: Performing the operation "Remove File" on target "C:\Users\admin\Documents\ab.pdf".


Sorry man. It doesn't work either. Your command will still remove all files existing in the folder (MyDocument in this case). I'm stuck to find out how to exclude single file name in Remove-Item list

It works for me; office.xlxs is not deleted.
